# How to replace a custom subview dynamically in a custom view class?

Tags: ios, uiview

GIVEN two views of type `RoundedIcon: UIView`:

- `class ContactRoundedIcon: RoundedIcon`
- `class PhoneRoundedIcon: RoundedIcon`

and a `ContactItem` class of type `UIView`

```
class ContactItem: UIView {
    var icon: RoundedIcon = PhoneRoundedIcon()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        addSubview(icon)
    }

    /* ... */

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        icon.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
        icon.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 0)
    )]
}
```

and a class `class ContactDropDownList: UIControl`

WHEN I assign `ContactRoundedIcon` to `contactItem.icon` property.

```
class ContactDropDownList: UIControl {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
        let contactItem = ContactItem()
        contactItem.icon = ContactRoundedIcon()
        self.addSubview(contactItem)
}
```

THEN the icon does not change from `PhoneRoundedIcon` to `ContactRoundedIcon`. At least I don't see it in a simulator.

The `ContactDropDownList` view is added as a subview in a storyboard. The rest of the views are written programmatically. While on their own, they are OK. The icon assignment in the `ContactItem` instance does not make any effect.

What's wrong? How to change the icon?

Comment: Do you set a `frame`for `ContactRoundedIcon` in its `init`?

Comment: I use autolayout (constriants) typed from code. Autolayout works OK, I've double checked that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class ContactItem: UIView {
    var icon: RoundedIcon = PhoneRoundedIcon() {
        didSet {
            // get rid of the old icon
            oldValue.removeFromSuperview()
            // add a new one
            addSubview(icon)
            // setup layout (I'm not sure if you use autolayout or set frames, but I don't see any layout setup, which might also be a problem)
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        addSubview(icon)
    }
    ...
}
```

In `didSet` you need to get rid of the old icon, and add a new one to the view. Otherwise it's just normal that you see the old one (the `commonInit' gets called in initializer, when you set a new icon, it is all set up and it won't get called again).

Moreover, you haven't shown any layout code, so make sure you set frames properly, or constraints if you are using autolayout.

**EDIT**

The old view does not have to be removed, per se. But you should remove it, unless you really have any good reason to keep it there. First of all, you want the unused objects to be deallocated. By keeping it in the view you are keeping it retained. Second of all, if the new `icon` has some transparent parts (or is smaller than the old one) the parts of the old `icon` would be visible. Which I guess you don't want either.

Comment: Hi MIlan, thanks!. Could you explain why the old view needs to be removed, while assigning a different view object and calling `setNeedsDipslay(`) does not work?

Comment: For the first question, see my edit of the question. for the second: I would expect that `setNeedsDisplay()` works (I have no reason to believe otherwise). Why it does not do what you expect I cannot tell. The code you provided does not show how you set frames of your UI components, nor shows constraints of the autolayout. If you don't set frames nor constraints for autolayout, then you have your answer - the view does not know where to place its subviews. If you set the frames and constraints, then you would have to show us that code to help you with that.

Comment: Milan, thanks for further explanation. I have edited the question to add the layout code. All the views are constraints based. The `RoundedIcon` class  sets the icon's height and width. All the views have `translateAutoresizingMask` set to `false`. Generally speaking your solution worked splendidly, I just wondered why setNeedsDisplay did not work.

Comment: As a sidenote to that autolayout constraints - I just hope that you set them also in `didSet` for the new `icon`. Back to the `setNeedsDisplay` - what do you mean that it does not work? When do you call it, what do you expect to happen and what happens?

Comment: Yes, I have added new constraints. The old ones are removed along with the old view. Back to the `setNeedsDisplay` - My thought was that if I assign a new view object reference to the icon property, the old one at some point in time will automatically get deallocated. I expected that the old view will be replaced and what I need is to redraw the view. But this did not work.

Comment: @TomaszNazarenko `UIView` holds strong references to its subviews, so to be deallocated, each `addSubview(icon)` has to have a pairing `icon.removeFromSuperview()`. Otherwise, even though you don't hold a strong reference to the `icon`, `icon`'s superview will keep it existing, and moreover, it will keep showing it on the screen! So do I understand it correctly that you don't call `setNeedsDisplay()` and the question about it was just a reaction to your assumption on how that works?